# Check if exists, if so, update by 1++, if not insert

Tags: php, mysql

Hey guys quick question, I currently have an insert statement
`$query= "INSERT into new_mail VALUES ('$to1', '0')";` **where fields are username, and message_number**
Currently what I would do to check if the entry exists, is do a select query then check the number of rows with `mysql_num_rows` (php). If rows==1 then I get the current **message_number** and set it equal to

```
$row['message_number']+1.
```

Then I update that entry with another query.

Is there an easier way to do all this in just mysql with just one query (check if exists, if not insert, if so update message_number, increase by 1)?

Comment: Are you using the mysqli extension?

Comment: well it comes default with php, but I am not using that format yet, however I do intend to change all my queries to mysqli in a couple weeks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`INSERT...ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html). The MySQL manual has an example which does almost exactly what you need:

```
INSERT INTO table (a,b,c) VALUES (1,2,3)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE c=c+1;
```

To make this work you need to add a UNIQUE index on the column that you use to check for duplicates. There is one important warning though:

> In general, you should try to avoid using an ON DUPLICATE KEY  clause on tables with multiple unique indexes.

Answer (score 5):

Depending on how your table is structured, you may be able to use the [`ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) (link to the MySQL manual) feature of `INSERT`:

```
INSERT into new_mail VALUES ('$to1', '0') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE message_number=message_number+1
```

Answer (score 3):

Got a little confused by your question and your table structures but I think you want something like this.

```
INSERT INTO new_mail (username, message_number)
VALUES ($username, $message_number) 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE message_number=message_number + 1;
```

This is presuming `username` is your primary key (more likely something like userid).  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: The ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE answers are better, but you *could* do this (eludes the select query):

Assuming you're using the mysqli extenson:

```
$db = //Some construction of mysqli object;
$sql = 'UPDATE tablename SET RowValue = RowValue + 1 WHERE message_number = ?';
$updateStatement = $db->prepare($sql);
$updateStatement->bind_param('i', $message_number);
$message_number = //Set message number;
$updateStatement->execute();
if ($updateStatement->affectedRows == 0) {
    $sql = 'INSERT INTO tablename (RowValue,  message_number) VALUES (?, ?)';
    $insertStatement = $db->prepare($sql);
    $insertStatement->bind_param('ii', $rowValue, $messageNumber);
    $rowValue = something;
    $messageNumber = something;
    $insertStatement->execute();
}
```

Comment: You could use this technique in conjuction with my solution but using mysql prepared statements is only going to be benifical if your expecting to execute this query multiple times (eg hundreds)

Comment: @bigstylee: The benefit is not for performance reasons, it's for security reasons. You should be using prepared statements no matter how many times you execute the query.

Comment: A valid point but in my humble opinion, the same level of security can be achieved with alot less code (therefore more readable/maintainable) without using this technique.  But I do agree there are good arguments for both cases.

Comment: @bigstylee: I don't see how you can do it with less code. Even using mysql_real_escape_string you still have at least one line per variable for escaping.

Comment: I do agree, the duplicate keys are better, but I found your answer useful for reference since I do want to start learning mysqli format quite soon for injection security. thanks Billy.