# if name exists save as name(1) name(2) and so on

Tags: php, mysql

There's a mysql database that stores ids and names, when users are creating names with a form they can create existent names since unique ids are the `ids` such as:

```
d49f2c32f9107c87c7bb7b44f1c8f297 name
2fa9c810fbe082900975f827e8ed9408 name
```

what i want to do is saving the second "name" -> "name(1)" when inserting into database.

So far what I've got is this as the idea

lets say the name entered is 'name'

```
$input = 'name';
```

select the name we want to check from mysql database

```
mysql_query(SELECT * FROM  `table` WHERE  `name` =  '$input');
```

if the result exists, then insert as `$input.'(1)'`

my question is what if name exists, and name(1) also exists, then how can i add the name(2) there...

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2614679/check-if-exists-if-so-update-by-1-if-not-insert

Comment: @yes123: Begging for accepts? And for an answer that executes god knows how many queries?

Comment: accorind to the OP that is a coincidence and is more likely to happen not often

Comment: anyway yes this is a dup you should vote for closjng

Comment: @yes123 because you answer is not going to get accepted?

Comment: @yes123 - ha - ok, my words have been eaten. Good job you didn't succeed in getting the question closed then!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$i = 1;
$sourceName = $name;
while( sql "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE name = '$name'" ) {

  $name = $sourceName.' ('.$i.')';
  $i++;
}
```

At this point you have the final `$name` (with `$i` counting the iteration)

Comment: While this will work, it's probably the worst way of doing it. Putting an SQL call as the parameters for a loop could lead to some pretty impressive problems, especially if the user was called (for instance) '%'.

Comment: This would find "Bob", but would it find "Bob(1)"?

Answer (score 3):

You could return the number of people with that name in the database, then add 1 to that number.

```
SELECT COUNT(id) FROM table WHERE name LIKE '$input(%)');
```

Comment: Unless it was zero, of course :) 

Also, it will confuse Matt and Matthew (for example).

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE name = '$input' OR name LIKE '$input(%)'
```

Note that for this to work, you'd need to escape any percent signs in `$input` in the LIKE clause, otherwise they'll be treated as wildcards.

Answer (score 0):

Use a regex that checks for integers between two parentheses at the end of the string. If there exists an integer, add 1 to it.

Answer (score 0):

You could also attempt to do it the other way around, make `name` field unique and try to input it in a while loop, if it fails add `($i)` and do `$i++` every iteration.

//edit:
The problem with using solutions that do a `like` comparison is that you will get false positives, for instance `$hi%` will also count `hippie`. Which gives you unnecessary (1) additions!