# View counter - how to only count up once per user? - PHP / Laravel 4

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4

I’m planning a view count coded in PHP for a blog. The purpose of the counter is to indicate how often a blog post is read, like StackOverflow shows 'viewed n times' on question pages.

First I wanted to store the counter data in files but through research I changed my mind to use MySQL with several InnoDB tables as these perform faster than HDD lookups, are less laborious in the long run and ship with useful functions natively.

The problem I’m stuck at is **how to only count up once per user?**

Restricting IP’s is not a solution, because of dynamic IP’s and networks mostly having a single IP sharing the connection with all connected devices (e.g. school, office, public access points).

**EDIT:**

Inspired by [fideloper’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17515371/2493918) I’m noodling over a session based solution.

I’m using a separate database table for sessions already, so I’ll incorporate this into the solution as suggested.

This is what I have got so far (using [Laravel 4](http://laravel.com/) with [Eloquent ORM](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent)):

**SQL Tables Setup:**

```
-- 
-- Sessions Table
-- 
CREATE TABLE sessions (
    id VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    payload TEXT NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    last_activity INT(11) NOT NULL,

    UNIQUE INDEX sessions_id_unique (id)
) COLLATE='utf8_unicode_ci' ENGINE=InnoDB;

-- 
-- Views Table
-- 
CREATE TABLE post_views (
    id INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    post_id INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    sess_id VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    viewed_at TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY (id)
) COLLATE='utf8_unicode_ci' ENGINE=InnoDB;

-- 
-- Posts Table
-- 
CREATE TABLE posts (
    id INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    user_id INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    title VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    excerpt TEXT NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    slug VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    content LONGTEXT NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    ...

    views INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',

    PRIMARY KEY (id)
) COLLATE='utf8_unicode_ci' ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

**PHP Views Counter Class:**

```
<?php namespace Services\Posts;
/**
 * Blog Post Views Counter
 *
 * Using Laravel 4 with Eloquent ORM
 */

class ViewsCounter {

    public $post_id;

    /**
     * Sets the post id
     * 
     * @param  int $id
     * @return void
     */
    public function setPostID($id)
    {
        $this->post_id = $id;
    }

    /**
     * Handles the view count
     * 
     * @return bool  True or false on failure
     */
    public function countView()
    {
        // Get the post data from the db
        try
        {
            $post = \Post::findOrFail($this->post_id);
        }
        catch (\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException $e)
        {
            return false;
        }

        // Get the current session id
        $sess_id = session_id();

        // Check if this view was already counted by 
        // looking up the session id in the views table
        $post_views = \PostViews::where('sess_id', '=', $sess_id)
                            ->where('post_id', '=', $this->post_id)
                            ->remember(10)
                            ->first();

        // The sess_id was not found so count the view
        if (empty($post_views))
        {
            $post_views->post_id = $this->post_id;
            $post_views->sess_id = $sess_id;
            $post_views->viewed_at = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
            $post_views->save();

            // A cronjob is run every 24 hours to count the views per 
            // post and update the count values in the posts table.
            // The post_views table will be truncated when done.
        }

        return true;
    }

}
```

Suggestions appreciated.

Comment: Simply what have you tried ?!
Which is in simple words SHOW SOME CODE !

Comment: Get current count from the database, add 1 to it and save the incremented value back into the database.

Comment: `found quite a lot. But unfortunately the data is ancient`. You have the knowledge. `I'm using the Laravel Framework version 4` You have the technology....Take the code and adapt it to Laravel?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2614679/check-if-exists-if-so-update-by-1-if-not-insert

Comment: I see my question needs a clarification!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The question of counting +1 views **per user** is an interesting one, as you need to take sessions into account.

You'll really need to do +1 count per session ID (since it gets regenerated per user but is more likely to get you +1 view count per user per visit...depending on your code). Note that this means users who visit the site again in a new session will get a view count counted again.

If you need to track down session ID's, you may want to do the following:

1. Add a new database row per view (vs incrementing a single value). This way you can track session ID along with the view count (This also means an eventually large table!)
2. Only add a new row if session ID is not found (if found, user already has +1 view count in this visit).
3. For some scalability: Add a second table which tracks the number of visits per view. Have this get updated regularly using CRON or similar. You can then always write to one table (optimize table for writes) and read from the other table (optimize for reads).
4. For extra scalability, use the second table to count up view count per 24 hour period. Then you can delete the views from the view count table. This way, you're never filling up your view count table to huge proportions, but you are saving up your total view count per 24 hour period.

Feel free to shorten that 24 hour period up as well. You may (will) end up having some extra view counts being counted at the time that the view count is updated and the session ID's to compare against get deleted.

Hope that sparks some ideas for you.

Comment: This is an answer I was looking for! Thank you very much @fideloper. You definately caused some ideas to spark :P BTW. I have used some of your blog posts as inspiration for own coding implementations before.